# Microsoft Access 2016 Import Text Wizard System Resource Exceeded

Tags: database, ms-access, office365, ms-office, ms-access-2016

I am trying to import a .txt file into Microsoft Access 2016.

1. The text file is 868,508 KB
2. The file contains 1439253 records
3. I am using the import wizard and right before the import finishes and the table displays I am getting a "System Resource Exceeded" error.
4. 64 bit OS with 32GB RAM

I have tried the following

1. Changing set affinity from all to 0
2. Running a repair on Office 365

I have tried to import old versions of the .txt file I was successful with and also receive the same error. Colleagues are able to take the same steps without encountering the error.

Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Some longshots: If it's a new install of Access, check you have the 64-bit version of Office/Access too. If it's an existing Access file, try the 'compact and repair' command within Access (though I presume you've already done this).

Comment: In VBA Immediate window execute this line: `DAO.DBEngine.SetOption dbMaxLocksPerFile, 3000000` and try import again.

Comment: Check for any differences between your Windows updates and those of your successful colleagues.